# Synchronizing variable write with subsequent read

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, cpu-architecture, low-level

There are two threads executed on different CPU cores:

```
t1: x = true
t2: print(x)
```

x is initially false.

if t1 is first executed it may happen that x is still in CPU write buffer and t2 prints false.

To synchronize these threads I could use mutexes:

```
t1:
   lock(mutex) 
   x = true
   unlock(mutex) 

t2: 
   lock(mutex) 
   print(x)
   unlock(mutex)
```

then if t1 executes first t2 will always print true. This solution is working but has two disadvantages:

1. it is slow
2. it not conveying my intention well. It looks like I want to achieve mutual exclusion but in fact I want to propagate changes immediately.

My intention here is that if t1 gets preempted by t2 then t2 knows that t1 has started doing something by signalized it by x = true so now t2 knows to take different code branch because t1 is up to something. If t2 executes branch if (x == false) when t1 set x to true that would be a failure.

So are there better or more efficient ways to achieve what I want? I'm interested in c++ code as well as how underlying CPU (may be x86) will execute that code (e.g. memory barriers etc).

Comment: It sounds like a plain atomic might fit right in.

Comment: Note that while memory ordering and memory visibility are independent concepts, they are related. Memory visibility tells you which *past* stores are currently visible to other thread but if you don't sync threads there no meaning for *past*. AFAIK there is not a C++ function to control memory visibility alone, instead it is joined with the sync primitives (see acquire and release semantics).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: `atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release)` (effectively a store barrier) or `mo_seq_cst` (full barrier) are sort of like visibility-control, if I'm understanding the distinction you're making.

Comment: @MargaretBloom @PeterCordes Also `(void)x.load()` controls visibility of past stores but that's the past of some other previous load of `x` whose result wasn't thrown away but that lacked acquire.

Answer (score 0):

If I read that properly, you have a somewhat visible and complicated workload which t1 will take on, and you are looking to advise lurkers (t2..n) to not bother looking because some flag is set.   You can completely do this, and if your OS is so poorly implemented that you can record non-contested mutex overhead, then switch OSes.

If you make a benchmark of the two threads you have shown, however, you will measure what should be an extremely unlikely operational pattern.   At the very least, you would not expect this pattern unless the system were idle, thus none of this matters.

I tend to prefer a signal-based design, where a meaningful change in (the calculated) status of some important variable results in alerting those who have expressed an interest in that variable.